# Unity How to detect sprite mssing? or null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to detect image sprite is "Missing" or "None"

1. [image]
2. [image]

When I Get this sprite , They all got "null" like this , 
So How do I know it is "Missing" or "None" ?
[image]

PS : I want to know it is missing or none , it is different situations for me.

Comment: `whatever.sprite == null`, Unity overrides the `==` operator and `Equals` method to make this easy for you.

Comment: @Draco18s yes I know that , I want to know it is missing or none , it is
different situations for me.

Comment: @TimChang missing and none are the same thing - they would both resolve to null.

Comment: Can you give more context as to why you need this to work? Since we might be able to give an alternative suggestion compared to what you are currently doing.

Comment: @Kaynn I Write unit test for my UI, so I want to check all missing , and if sprite is none, it ok , because sometimes we set sprite at runtime, but missing sprite is  obviously wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unity throws different exceptions for different reasons why the reference is `null` when trying to access them!

This is also the reason why you should [strongly avoid `someObject == null`](https://jacx.net/2015/11/20/dont-use-equals-null-on-unity-objects.html) checks. Unity has [overwritten](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it) the behavior of `== null` for the type `Object` (basically the mother class of most Unity built-in types) and even if an object appears to be `null` it still stores some information like - as just mentioned - the reason why it is `null`.

So you could use a little "trick" and simply try to access a field and check which exception exactly you get within `try - catch` blocks:

```
public void CheckReference(Object reference)
{
    try
    {
        var blarf = reference.name;
    }
    catch (MissingReferenceException) // General Object like GameObject/Sprite etc
    {
        Debug.LogError("The provided reference is missing!");
    }
    catch (MissingComponentException) // Specific for objects of type Component
    {
        Debug.LogError("The provided reference is missing!");
    }
    catch (UnassignedReferenceException) // Specific for unassigned fields
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("The provided reference is null!");
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException) // Any other null reference like for local variables
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("The provided reference is null!");
    }
}
```

---

Example

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Renderer renderer;
    public Collider collider;

    private void Awake()
    {
        renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        Destroy(renderer);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) return;

        CheckReference(renderer); // MissingComponentException
        CheckReference(collider); // UnassignedReferenceException

        Sprite sprite = null;

        CheckReference(sprite);   // NullReferenceException

        sprite = Sprite.Create(new Texture2D(1, 1), new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1), Vector2.zero);
        DestroyImmediate(sprite);
        CheckReference(sprite);   // MissingReferenceException
    }

    public void CheckReference(Object reference)
    {
        try
        {
            var blarf = reference.name;
        }
        catch (MissingReferenceException) // General Object like GameObject/Sprite etc
        {
            Debug.LogError("The provided reference is missing!");
        }
        catch (MissingComponentException) // Specific for objects of type Component
        {
            Debug.LogError("The provided reference is missing!");
        }
        catch (UnassignedReferenceException) // Specific for unassigned fields
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("The provided reference is null!");
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException) // Any other null reference like for local variables
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("The provided reference is null!");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That is genius.

Comment: This is a great solution, and I think it was working for me in the past, but right now it isn't working (Unity 2021.3.4).

Your test script still works as expected — I'm getting a MissingReferenceException on the sprite after the DestroyImmediate.

But, it doesn't work if I delete the sprite normally in the editor. e.g. Add a SpriteRenderer component, assign a Sprite, and then delete the Sprite from the project. The editor field shows as "Missing" rather than "None," but I'm getting a NullReferenceException rather than a MissingReferenceException.