# null GameObject becomes non-null when I convert to object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a particular function which can take an `object` as an argument. This is so it can be either a MonoBehaviour or a GameObject:

The wierd thing is, when I convert a null `GameObject` to an `Object`, it no longer appears as null:

```
public class EquipmentSlots : MonoBehaviour {

  // This is null: it hasn't been set in the inspector
  public GameObject offHandEquipLocation;

  void Start () {
    Validation.RequireField(
      "offHandEquipLocation",
      offHandEquipLocation
    ) 
  }

}

public class Validation : MonoBehaviour {
  public static void RequireField(string name, object field) {
    if (field == null) {
      Debug.Log($"{name} field is unset");
    }
  }
}
```

The `Log` call never gets run here, because the object is not null.

If I put `Debug.Log(offHandEquipLocation == null)` in the `Start()` function, it prints `true`. If I put `Debug.Log(field == null)` in the `RequireField()` method, it prints `false`.

Is there a way I can see if the `object` is null?

Comment: don't use `== null` rather use the `bool` operator `if(field)`

Comment: @derHugo can't do that exact code, because `field` is an `object` and therefore can't be used in that way. I know there are workarounds, I'm really just trying to understand why I see this behavior.

Comment: @derHugo I want to see if there's a way I can change just the `RequireField()` method to make this work, since there are     actually many `Start()` functions like this and it'd be more work to change them all.

Comment: Then Why are you passing it as `object`? If it is of type `GameObject` rather use `Object` (UnityEngine.Object) ... Unity has [overwritten](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/) he bahvior for `== null` for the type `Object` (basically all Unity built-in types)

Comment: You might btw be interrested in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055025/unity-how-to-detect-sprite-mssing-or-null/58056372#58056372) about determin **why** a certain reference is `null` ;)

Comment: @derHugo actually I am using this method with objects of other types as well. `string` for example. Every type I need can be coerced to `object`, but not necessarily `Object`. And, this approach does work for everything other than the game objects.

Comment: well as you see it will not work (properly and in all cases) for anything being of type `Object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very first thought in general on this: **Do not do it ^^**

There is one issue with this: You change the stacktrace of the call. By passing the null check to a static class when you see the eror in the console you can not like before directly see where it was thrown/logged from, directly go to the according code line by double clicking it and can't (that easy) highlight the according object "context" in the hierarchy.

So I would always keep the checks as close to the actual usage as possible and rather do it like

```
if(!offHandEquipLocation) Debug.LogError($"{nameof(offHandEquipLocation)} is not referenced!", this);
```

The whole sense of `Debug.Log` is making your life easier when debugging ;) Using the above approach offers way more advantages than the fact that using your approach you don't have to type `Debug.LogError($"{nameof(offHandEquipLocation)} is not referenced!", this);` multiple times.

---

As others and I already mentioned the reason why it doesn't work as you expect is Unity's [custom `== null`](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/) behavior for the type [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) from which most built-in types in particular `GameObject`, `ScriptableObject` and `Component` inherit.

Even though an [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) "might appear to be" or better said returns a value **equal to the value of** `null` Unity actually still stores some meta information in the reference in order to throw custom exceptions (`MissingReferenceException`, `MissingComponentException`, `UnassignedReferenceException`) which are more self explanatory then a simple `NullReferenceException` (as you can also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055025/unity-how-to-detect-sprite-mssing-or-null/58056372#58056372)). It therefore actually is not `null` in the underlying `object` type.

As soon as you convert it to `object` the custom `== null` behavior is gone but the underlying `object` still exists and therefoe you get `field == null` → `false`

---

However a solution might be creating a simple overload using the [`bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) for [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html). This replaces the `null` check and means something like `This object is referenced, exists, and was not destroyed yet.`. And keep using `== null` for anything else

```
public static void RequireField(string name, object field) 
{
    if (field == null) Debug.LogError($"{name} field is unset");
}

public static void RequireField(string name, Object field) 
{
    if (!field) Debug.LogError($"{name} field is unset");
}
```

Now you can use both. As a little note: I wouldn't use a verbal `string` for the first parameter but instead always pass it inusing `nameof` to make it more secure for renamings

```
var GameObject someObject;
var string someString;

Validation.validate(nameof(someObject), someObject);
Validation.validate(nameof(someString), someString);
```

---

A little sidenote regarding your argument for using this on e.g. `string` in general:

As soon as this is a `public` or `[SerializedField]` field in the Inspector for any `Component` (`MonoBehaviour`) or `ScriptableObject` it is always initialized by the Unity Inspector itself with a default value. Therefore a null check for any of e.g.

```
public int intValue;
[SerializeField] private string stringValue;
public Vector3 someVector;
public int[] intArray;
...
```

is redundant since none of them will ever be `null`. This counts for any serializable type as well so even if you have a custom class

```
[Serializable]
public class Example
{
    public string aField;
}
```

and then use a serialized field in your behaviour like e.g.

```
public List<Example> example;
```

also this one will never be `null`.

---

Btw as also mentioned already `Validation` should not inherit from `MonoBehaviour` but rather be

```
public static class Validation
{
    // only static members
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all this info. With this in mind, I think it's actually not going to work to make a method that takes any arbitrary field from my game and tells me if it's null. I think I'm going to need to check for the objects' existence before calling the method.

Comment: I totally get where you're coming from that it's better to simply be explicit even if it's a bit more repetitive/verbose. But, I'm a bit too far gone from that point already. My actual validation system is even more convoluted than I've let on.

Answer (score 2):

It's because Unity's `Object` [defines an `==` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_eq.html), which will return `true` if you compare a *destroyed* instance to `null`, even if the reference isn't actually `null`. By using `offHandEquipLocation`, you're calling this operator, while `object field` calls the [.NET `==` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators).

As has been stated, you can call `if` directly against GameObjects, since [Unity's `Object` defines an implicit conversion to `bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html), or you could cast to `System.Object` before performing a null check.

You should also be cautious about comparisons checking for referential null, and use [`ReferenceEquals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=netframework-4.8) if you really must know the difference between a nullref and a destroyed object.

Answer (score 1):

It is because GameObject's operator == is overridden. That is why `gameObject == null` is true, but after casted to object, it is not null anymore.
See [this](https://jacx.net/2015/11/20/dont-use-equals-null-on-unity-objects.html) and [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1224315/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-true-null-check.html)