# NullReferenceException problem in Unity when object is not null

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to troubleshoot the following piece of code which causes a NullReferenceException. Essentially when an object is created, I'm trying to have it register with my game manager class. This is the component for my object:

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Registering");
    if (gameObject != null)
    {
        GameMngr.Instance.RegisterAttraction(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Gameobject null");
    }
}
```

In my game manager I have the following:

```
public void RegisterAttraction(GameObject newAttraction)
{
    if (newAttraction != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Attempting to register gameObject");
        attractionLastID++;
        sceneAttractions.Add(attractionLastID, newAttraction);
        Debug.Log("Registered");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("unable to register: null provided");
    }
}
```

My console output is as following:

- Registering
- Attempting to register gameObject
- NullRefereceException

The fact that my code displays the attempting to register gameObject lines leads me to believe that my newAttraction variable is not null. Why do I get the error ?

Thank for the help

Comment: print the gameobject instanceID , maybe it is not a same gameobject ??

Comment: _"NullReferenceException problem in Unity when object is not null"_ -- the idea that you might get `NullReferenceException` when the reference is not in fact null is just nonsensical. The null value may be something other than the one you think it should be. But there is *definitely* a null value that you're trying to dereference. See proposed duplicate for complete details on how to debug the problem.

Comment: `GameMngr.Instance.RegisterAttraction(gameObject);` How to sure that it is set from your script ? , mabye it is from other script and you think it is from your script.

Comment: also make sure you [**never** use `== null`/`!= null` for references of type `Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069056/7111561) in Unity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where's attractionLastId defined by chance? Is it being initialized? Since you're doing a null check inside of your Start function already, try refactoring your RegisterAttraction function to look something like:

```
public void RegisterAttraction(GameObject newAttraction)
    {

            Debug.Log("Attempting to register gameObject");
            attractionLastID++;
            sceneAttractions.Add(attractionLastID, newAttraction);
            Debug.Log("Registered");
    }
```

I highly recommend setting a breakpoint on the beginning curly of RegisterAttraction. Take it step by step and hover over each variable to see which one is null.

Comment: Turns out that the issue was with sceneAttractions - it wasn't initialized early enough. Thanks for suggesting the breakpoint!